# Count specific days between two dates based on a rolling fortnight

Tags: javascript

I am creating a scheduled delivery system.

I put together the following script that counts the quantity of specific days of the week between two dates in dd/mm/yyyy format (UK).

```
var date0 = "01/02/2021";
var date1 = "31/01/2022";
var dayList = [1]; // Monday based on Sunday being 0
    
var test = countDays(dayList,parseDate(date0),parseDate(date1));
alert(test);
            
function parseDate(str) {
    var dmy = str.split('/');
    return new Date(+dmy[2],dmy[1] - 1,+dmy[0]);    
}           
            
function countDays(days,fromDate,toDate) {
    var ndays = 1 + Math.round((toDate-fromDate)/(24*3600*1000));
    var sum = function(a,b) {
        return a + Math.floor((ndays+(fromDate.getDay()+6-b)%7)/7);
    };
    return days.reduce(sum,0);
}
```

I this particular instance the `dayList=[1]` is 'Monday'. The script counts the number of Monday's between the two dates and we get the result 53 (because it happens that 01/02/2021 falls on a Monday).

This would works great if I want to find out how many Mondays were between two dates based on a rolling week.

How can I modify this to allow for a rolling fortnight?

For example I might want to find out how many weekly Mondays and alternate Fridays there are based on a rolling fortnight, not a rolling week. I have to allow for a mixture of weekly and fortnightly deliveries.

For example:
In this case the client wants a delivery every Monday and an extra delivery every other Friday.

```
Sat Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri 
         x                           x               x
```

Schedules vary enormously. The rolling fortnight starts on the start date provided by the user.

What I am looking for is the total number of days between a start and end date but I am struggling with factoring the 'rolling fortnight' aspect of this.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I came up with. I am sure that this can be expanded further but I have the ability to store an array of the delivery dates and (now that I have the total number of deliveries) I can calculate costs based on other information.

I hope this is of help.

```js
function parseDate(str) {
  //handles the dd/mm/yyyy format UK date
    var dmy = str.split('/');
    return new Date(+dmy[2], dmy[1] - 1, + dmy[0]);     
}           

var fromDate = parseDate(document.getElementById("startdate").value);   // convert the date to js date  
var toDate = parseDate(document.getElementById("enddate").value);   // convert the date to js date  
var thisDay = fromDate.getDay();

var thisWeek;
var thisValue;
var testWeek;
var testElement;    
var result = 0;

while (fromDate <= toDate) {
    if (thisDay >= 14) {
        thisDay = 1;
    }
    thisWeek = Math.ceil(thisDay / 7);
    for (i = 1; i <= 14; i++) {
        testElement = document.getElementById("day" + i);
        testWeek = Math.ceil(i / 7);
        if ((testElement.checked) && (thisDay == i) && (thisWeek == testWeek)) {
            result++;
        }
    }
    thisDay++;
    fromDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate() + 1);
}           
alert("Number of deliveries is: " + result);
```

```html
<input name="startdate" id="startdate" type="text" value="01/02/2021"/>
<input name="enddate" id="enddate" type="text" value="14/05/2021"/>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Mon</th>
            <th>Tue</th>
            <th>Wed</th>
            <th>Thu</th>
            <th>Fri</th>
            <th>Sat</th>
            <th>Sun</th>
            <th>Mon</th>
            <th>Tue</th>
            <th>Wed</th>
            <th>Thu</th>
            <th>Fri</th>
            <th>Sat</th>
            <th>Sun</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input class="tick checkboxgroup" type="checkbox" name="day1" id="day1" checked="checked"/></td>
            <td><input class="tick checkboxgroup" type="checkbox" name="day2" id="day2"/></td>
            <td><input class="tick checkboxgroup" type="checkbox" name="day3" id="day3"/></td>
            <td><input class="tick checkboxgroup" type="checkbox" name="day4" id="day4"/></td>
            <td><input class="tick checkboxgroup" type="checkbox" name="day5" id="day5"/></td>
            <td><input class="tick checkboxgroup" type="checkbox" name="day6" id="day6"/></td>
            <td><input class="tick checkboxgroup" type="checkbox" name="day7" id="day7"/></td>
            <td><input class="tick checkboxgroup" type="checkbox" name="day8" id="day8" checked="checked"/></td>
            <td><input class="tick checkboxgroup" type="checkbox" name="day9" id="day9"/></td>
            <td><input class="tick checkboxgroup" type="checkbox" name="day10" id="day10"/></td>
            <td><input class="tick checkboxgroup" type="checkbox" name="day11" id="day11"/></td>
            <td><input class="tick checkboxgroup" type="checkbox" name="day12" id="day12" checked="checked"/></td>
            <td><input class="tick checkboxgroup" type="checkbox" name="day13" id="day13"/></td>
            <td><input class="tick checkboxgroup" type="checkbox" name="day14" id="day14"/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could get the day names between the dates, and then use a `reduce` to count how many times each appears, and then use that to calculate how many deliveries there are:

```js
const start = new Date('2022-11-17T03:24:00');
const endDate = new Date('2022-12-31T03:24:00');

const getDaysBetweenDates = function*(s, e) {
  let currentDate = s;
  
  while (currentDate < e) {
    yield currentDate.toLocaleDateString("en-us", { weekday: 'long' });
    currentDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  }
}


const dayCounts = Array.from(getDaysBetweenDates(start, endDate))
  .reduce((p, c) => ({
    ...p,
    [c]: (p.hasOwnProperty(c) ? p[c] + 1 : 1)
  }), {});

console.log(dayCounts.Monday + Math.floor(dayCounts.Friday / 2));
```

Comment: Hi, This is an interesting solution. The snippet does not work (the function name is incorrect). I am not entirely sure how it works but the final ```console.log``` seems to rely on the user calculating the answer?

Comment: @arresteddevelopment ah nice spot, thanks. It gives you a list of the days and then counts them - so the output is a function of the days that appear between two given dates